# Google Sheets - Simple VLOOKUP with Double Drop Down Data Validation

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I have a simple request that combines Data Validation with VLOOKUP.

On my *Pending* worksheet, when you select a Website - it should create a dropdown in the next column showing only the email addresses assigned to that website within the *Profiles* worksheet. Lastly, when you select an Email in the newly created dropdown - the next column should show the correct Name that's assigned to that Email-Website combination.

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xmlMoKKj_3orAI4nm0tJglfk0nPPfS8LMyB6BcbdgQU/edit?usp=sharing) my Google Sheet:

Comment: Would a script solution be acceptable? it seems it is a limitation of the data validation to procure data from a formula. Trying to do it earlier but errors out **Please enter a valid range**. Doesn't work on **Custom formula** too.

Comment: A script would be acceptable absolutely if you feel that's the simplest solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script solution:

#### Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  const column = r.getColumn();
  const row = r.getRow();
  // if non header in 'Pending' sheet is edited and the outcome has a value  
  if (src.getSheetName() == 'Pending' && row > 1 && e.value) {
    // get data as a whole
    var data = e.source.getSheetByName('Profiles').getDataRange().getValues();
    // if A2:A is edited
    if (column == 1) { 
      // filter 1st column using e.value, then return 2nd column
      var emails = data.filter(row => row[0] == e.value).map(row => row[1]);
      // set data (list) validation to colB
      r.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(emails).build());
      // delete data in colB and colC
      src.getRange(row, column + 1, 1, 2).clearContent();
    }
    // if B2:B is edited
    else if (column == 2) {
      var colA = r.offset(0, -1).getValue();
      var colB = e.value;
      // only populate column C if both A and B has values
      if (colA && colB) {
        var name = data.filter(row => row[0] == colA && row[1] == colB)[0][2];
        // set value to colC
        r.offset(0, 1).setValue(name);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### New Data:

[image: new]

#### Modifying Data:

[image: edit]

Comment: This is really great thank you! Tiny issue is that when you delete all the values, the Email drop down arrow remains in place and there's no easy way to delete it (without deleting the cell). Apart from that it works perfectly and I understand the logic. Thank you https://snipboard.io/EhsznK.jpg

Comment: Hi @AntonyXenophontos, you can use [clearDataValidations()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#cleardatavalidations) to remove the data validation of a range. I opted to exclude it since I haven't considered that it is possible to have no drop down at all. But if it is needed in your case, feel free to add it.